# If I move comments to the chat can I use @?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

If I move the comments to the chat can I still answer to users (by using @username) who have commented before the move ?

Comment: One would have to try it out but my guess is probably not (i.e. you can't talk to people who are not in the chat room)

Comment: @Pekka웃 that's the reason I don't want to move the "discussion"... I fear to not be able to contact the commentators...

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, if the *entire* discussion is moved then you should be able to ping those whose comments are being moved. I would give it a try

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, the users have to join the room them self, they are not auto joined. It is similar how chat invites work

Comment: @Pekka웃 if you try, and survive to it, don't forget to post an answer. :D

Comment: I mean, if they don't join chat, that would indicate they don't want to chat, right? Why should they be notified? If they decide they DO want to chat, they'll see the messages when they get there.

Comment: @KevinB ok but when you use @ the user can get the notification when he come back on SO. if you have to chat, you have both people to be present at the same time...

Comment: Not necessarily. Chat doesn't have to be realtime, it can happen just like comments and still be useful.

Comment: @KevinB but my question is about if it's possible or not to to use @ to get a notification like we do with @ in a comment.  If the answer is no, then I don't want to use the chat...

Comment: the answer is "Yes, if certain requirements are met", said requirements being the user you're @targeting has joined the channel at some point in time.